# "filleted union" operation in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is quite likely to be wishful thinking, but consider the following MWE, which creates two tikz paths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[fill=blue] (0,0) to[out=0, in=180] (2,1) -- (2,1.5) to[out=180, in=0] (0,0.5);
    \path[fill=red] (0,0) to[out=0, in=180] (2,-1) -- (2,-0.5) to[out=180, in=0] (0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to somehow combine these two paths to get something that looks like this:

[image]

The idea is to union them together in a way that smooths out the join.

To clarify, what I'm hoping for is something that *takes the two paths as input* and transforms them to get the combined and smoothed path - see below for why.

Alternatively, if there's a way to just union them together and then smooth out all of the corners like this, then I can probably work with that as well. (Sorry for the wonky drawing, hopefully you can see what I mean.)

[image]

My goal ultimately is to draw diagrams like this one

[image]

...**but I'm not asking for code to draw this one diagram**. This will be part of a library I'm writing for drawing diagrams of this type. What I'm hoping to achieve is a way of automatically drawing the parts where the shaded areas split, without having to specify the curve individually each time.

My idea was that I could split some of the complex paths into components and then union them together - in the example it would be something like this

[image]

But if I would just union the red, green and yellow paths together (or paint them over each other) it would lead to sharp corners where they join, whereas the joins should ideally be smooth. So if it's possible to smooth out the corners somehow, the diagrams will look a lot better.

As I said I sort of imagine this isn't possible, but I'm often surprised by what's possible in tikz, so I figured it's worth asking.

Comment: It is surely possible, but I am not quite sure whether the right way to do this is a filled path (and not just a drawn line). It would be good if you could give a few examples how you wish to use this eventually.

Comment: @JasperHabicht that's a good point. I've edited in an example of the sort of thing I hope to achieve. Doing it with a single filled path would be completely fine, but then the problem would be how to automate it. My idea was that if I could split the shaded area up into distinct parts and then union them together in a smoothed way, then it would save me a huge amount of effort and make the library a lot easier to use.

Comment: Hm, the more edits you make, the more complex everything seems to be ... To be honest, I would probably just re-draw (`postaction`) the relevant paths with a certain line width and reduced opacity ... Also, this reminds me of the `mindmap` library.

Comment: @JasperHabicht oh, that gives me an idea. If there is a way to union the paths and get a path as a result (which I don't currently know if there is), then I could re-draw the path in white with a fat line width, and that would make all the inward-pointing corners look rounded. (I'd have to make the paths oversized to begin with, but I think that's no problem.)

Comment: (Hmm, but then would I be able to make the white line invisible when drawing the result over the top of the diagram? I don't know that either. I'm beginning to think I should just learn to live with a slightly pointier aesthetic for these diagrams.)

Comment: Did you look at the answers you got? I think, there are some answers in there for parts of your questions ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht I'd seen them but not your edit, which looks pretty amazing.

Comment: I don't know whether my answer is really that helpful. Anyways, if you have two paths, say `\path (0,0) to[out=90, in=90] (1,0);` and `\path (1,0) -- (0,0);`, you can just "unify" them by putting the paths together, so that it becomes one: `\path (0,0) to[out=90, in=90] (1,0) -- (0,0);`; or, to close the path properly, just: `\path (0,0) to[out=90, in=90] (1,0) -- cycle;`. You could do the same with the paths you show in your example. As for the curves, you would indeed need to somehow draw them (or try the `rounded corners` option which, however, might not really work for more complex paths.

Answer (score 1):

A first approach, with lines and arcs could be the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[scale=0.41,yshift=3cm]% the yshift is only for comparison
   (0,0) arc (90:50:2.7)   --++ (-40:1.9) arc (230:270:2.7) --++ (0,1.2)
         arc (270:230:2.7) --++ (140:1)  arc (230:130:0.8)  --++ (40:1)
         arc (130:90:2.7)  --++ (0,1.2)  arc (90:130:2.7)   --++ (220:1.9)
         arc (310:270:2.7) -- cycle;
% original paths
\path[fill=blue] (0,0) to[out=0, in=180] (2,1)  -- (2,1.5)  to[out=180, in=0] (0,0.5);
\path[fill=red]  (0,0) to[out=0, in=180] (2,-1) -- (2,-0.5) to[out=180, in=0] (0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that takes the paths you already have:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[fill=blue] (0,0.25) to[out=0, in=180] (2,1.25) --
        (2,0.75) to[out=180, in=180, looseness=2] (2,-0.75) -- 
        (2,-1.25) to[out=180, in=0] (0,-0.25) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or maybe something like this on the basis of a `\pic`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/fork/.style n args={3}{
        code={
            \coordinate (-A) at #1; \path (-A);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\forkcoordax}{\forkcoorday}
            \coordinate (-B) at #2; \path (-B);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\forkcoordbx}{\forkcoordby}
            \coordinate (-C) at #3; \path (-C);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\forkcoordcx}{\forkcoordcy}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\forkdist}{
                min(
                    veclen(\forkcoordbx-\forkcoordax,\forkcoordby-\forkcoorday),
                    veclen(\forkcoordcx-\forkcoordax,\forkcoordcy-\forkcoorday)
                )
            }
            \path[pic actions] 
                (-A) to[out=0, in=180] (-B)
                to[out=180, in=180, distance={\forkdist *0.5pt}] (-C)
                to[out=180, in=0] (-A);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[red, fill, draw, very thick] at (0,1) 
        {fork={(0,0)}{(2,0.75)}{(2,-0.75)}};

    \pic[blue, fill, draw, line width=0.5cm, rotate=180] at (0,-1) 
        {fork={(0,0)}{(2,0.75)}{(2,-0.75)}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This should also more or less work for what you show in you latest edit:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/fork/.style n args={3}{
        code={
            \coordinate (-A) at #1; \path (-A);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\forkcoordax}{\forkcoorday}
            \coordinate (-B) at #2; \path (-B);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\forkcoordbx}{\forkcoordby}
            \coordinate (-C) at #3; \path (-C);
            \pgfgetlastxy{\forkcoordcx}{\forkcoordcy}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\forkdist}{
                min(
                    veclen(\forkcoordbx-\forkcoordax,\forkcoordby-\forkcoorday),
                    veclen(\forkcoordcx-\forkcoordax,\forkcoordcy-\forkcoorday)
                )
            }
            \path[pic actions] 
                (-A) to[out=0, in=180] (-B)
                to[out=180, in=180, distance={\forkdist *0.5pt}] (-C)
                to[out=180, in=0] (-A);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[blue, fill, draw, line width=0.5cm] (fork A) at (0,0) 
        {fork={(0,0)}{(2,0.75)}{(2,-0.75)}};

    \pic[blue, fill, draw, line width=0.5cm] (fork B) at (fork A-C) 
        {fork={(0,0)}{(2,0)}{(2,-1.25)}};

    \pic[blue, fill, draw, line width=0.5cm] (fork C) at (fork A-B) 
        {fork={(0,0)}{(2,-0.5)}{(2,0.5)}};

    \pic[blue, fill, draw, line width=0.5cm] (fork D) at ([xshift=1cm]fork C-B) 
        {fork={(0,0)}{(2,-2)}{(2,0)}};

    \draw[blue, line width=0.5cm] (fork C-B) -- (fork D-A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Admittedly, things may look a bit strange if the *y* distance of the two branches is too small or if the two branches end at too different *x* positions. Well, at least it might serve as a starting point ...